# Can't add hotmail.com address into Gmail 5.0

Tags: gmail, 5.0-lollipop, accounts

I tried under KitKat and Lollipop on my Nexus 4 but I can't add my old account. I also tried both manual and automatic setup, but same result: credentials are incorrect.

Any solutions about this? Should I have entered different parameters during the manual setup?

EDIT:

POP3 with default parameters: server hotmail.com, port 110, security STARTTLS

IMAP with default parameters: server hotmail.com, port 143, security STARTTLS

Exchange, which doesn't give the possibility to change any parameters

Comment: What parameters did you enter during the manual setup? Knowing what parameter you tried will help prevent us from suggesting ones you already tried.

Comment: See updated original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have two-step verification enabled on your hotmail account? If you do, that extra layer of security can trip up GMail. You'll need to create an "App Password", which should be a setting in your Hotmail settings.

From [Microsoft's Two-step Verification FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/two-step-verification-faq):

> Some apps (like the mail apps on some smartphones) or devices (like
>   the Xbox 360, for example) can't prompt you to enter a security code
>   when you try to sign in. If you get an incorrect password error with
>   an app or device, you'll need to create a unique app password to sign
>   in. Once you've signed in with your app password, you're all set to
>   use that app or device. You'll need to create and sign in with an app
>   password once for each app or device that can't prompt you for a
>   security code.
>
> 1. Sign in to your Microsoft account.
> 2. Under **Password and security info**, tap or click **Edit security info**.
> 3. If you're prompted for a security code here, enter it and tap or click **Submit**.
> 4. Under **App passwords**, tap or click **Create a new app password**.
>
>    A new app password is generated and appears on your screen.
> 5. Switch to the app or device for which you need the password, and enter the app password displayed on the screen.
>
> For more info about signing in to specific devices, see App passwords
>   and two-step verification.

Comment: It worked, that's great! Thanks. I can finally uninstall the Outlook app.

Comment: Note: For me the Gmail app defaulted to "hotmail.com" for the server. I had to change this to imap-mail.outlook.com and smtp-mail.outlook.com respectively. I also had to use SSL/TSL for IMAP and couldn't use STARTTLS.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps as seen @ [how-to-set-up-hotmail-on-android](http://zusiddiqui.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/how-to-set-up-hotmail-on-android/):
...
...

1) Tap on “Email” in your app drawer

2) You should see the Email Setup screen. Type in your email address and password. Tap Next.

- If you encounter an error, repeat Steps 1 and 2 (DON’T press Next). Move on to Step 3.

3) Once you’ve typed in your details, tap on “Manual Setup”.

4) Select “Exchange” from the list of options.

5) Fill out the fields as indicated below in the Account Setup window:

```
Domain\Username: delete the “\” and type in your full email address
Password: type in your Hotmail password
Server: type in “debug-m.hotmail.com”.
    If that doesn’t work, repeat Steps 1 – 4 and use “m.hotmail.com”
    If that doesn’t work either, repeat Steps 1 – 4 and use “blu-m.hot mail.com”
Make sure the Security Type is “SSL/TLS”
```

6) Tap on “Next”.

7) Choose whatever options you want (how frequently it should check for email, how much it should sync etc.). Tap on “Next”.

8) A little loading icon may appear as it syncs your email account.

9) Congratulations! Your email is all set up and you can now set a name for the mailbox.

Your account should be completely set up by now. It should be syncing your email as you read this very sentence. Once again, this setup has only been tested on @hotmail.com and @hotmail.co.uk accounts.

...
...

*Alternatively, you can always create a new GMail account and integrate your hotmail one with it (Allow you to seen your hotmail emails inside the GMail interface) as seen @ [guidingtech.com](http://www.guidingtech.com/1601/integrate-yahoo-hotmail-gmail/) and then add the GMail account.*

Comment: I tried to accommodate these steps to the GMail app but it didn't work.